# Setup IIS 7.5 to render svgz files in browsers

Tags: iis, svg, gzip, svgz

I have IIS 7.5 server on Windows 7.
On a particular web page there is a SVG element.
On this SVG element, there is an image element:

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="images/image.svgz"></image>
```

I have configured:

- mime type: svgz image/svg+xml
- enabled both compression types, static and dynamic

When I try to open the standalone file I see this message:

> **This page contains the following errors:**
>
> error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: this is the code from a test page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg height="200" version="1.1" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="images/image.svgz"></image>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to open the .svg file in the IE9+ Browser? If so, IE does read svg files.

Comment: Let's say I want to open compressed .svg files, known to have .svgz extension.